# How to stop nested computation and close Toplevel window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `Toplevel` window in a tkinter script, which contains two progress bars corresponding to a nested loop. I want to add a stop button in the Toplevel window to terminate the execution and close the Toplevel window but not the root.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel,Button,Label,TOP,BOTH,DoubleVar
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import time 

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='lightgray')
root.wm_title("Main")


progress_window = Toplevel()

progress_window.attributes('-topmost', 'true')
progress_window.configure(bg='lightgrey')
progress_window.wm_title("Progress")
progress_window_label = Label(root, text="")
progress_window.geometry('600x300')
progress_window_label.pack()

M=4 # outer loop
N=5 # inner loop

progress1_var=DoubleVar()
progress1bar=Progressbar(master=progress_window,variable=progress1_var,length=M)    
progress1bar.pack(side=TOP,ipady=5,fill=BOTH,expand=True)
progress1_var.set(0)
progress1bar.update()
progress1bar_label=Label(master=progress_window,text='Bar1',bg='lightgray')
progress1bar_label.pack(side=TOP,pady=5,fill=BOTH, expand=True)

progress2_var = DoubleVar()
progress2bar=Progressbar(master=progress_window,variable=progress2_var,length=N)
progress2bar.pack(side=TOP,ipady=5,fill=BOTH, expand=True)
​progress2_var.set(0)
progress2bar.update()
progress2bar_label=Label(master=progress_window,text='Bar2',bg='lightgray')
progress2bar_label.pack(side=TOP,pady=5,fill=BOTH, expand=True)

def _stop():
    return

stop_button=Button(master=progress_window, text="Cancel",command=_stop)
stop_button.pack(side=TOP,pady=5,fill=BOTH, expand=True)


​for t in range(M):

       ​progress1_var.set(t/M)
       ​progress1bar_label.config(text='Bar 1:   '+str(round((t+1)/M*100,3))+'%')
       ​progress1bar.update()

       ​progress2_var.set(0)
       ​progress2bar.update()
   ​
       ​for i in range(N):
           ​progress2_var.set(i/N)
           ​time.sleep(1.0) #Sleep to slow down execution and view progress window
           ​progress2bar_label.config(text='Bar 2:  '+str(round((i+1)/N*100,3))+'%')
           ​progress2bar.update()


​progress_window.destroy()
root.mainloop()
```

The stop button appears where it should but does not function and stop the execution. This has to be a very fundamental error, but I don't see how to correct it.

Comment: I hope you know that calling `_stop()` does absolutely nothing (except waste an extremely small amount of resources), I would suggest raising some flag and having some if statements in those loops that will break them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few modifications, primarily the addition of `protocol` for `root` and `progress_window`.

I've also created a flag called `killed` that is used to break the `for` loops. I've placed them in a function that is called by `after`.

This stops the `TclError: Invalid command name .!toplevel.!label2`

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button, Label, TOP, BOTH, DoubleVar
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import time 

killed  =  False

root  =  Tk()
root.configure(bg = 'lightgray')
root.wm_title("Main")

root.update()

progress_window  =  Toplevel()

def stop():
    global killed
    killed = True
    progress_window.destroy()
    root.destroy()

# Added protocol controls for exit

root.protocol( "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", stop )
progress_window.protocol( "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", stop )

progress_window.attributes('-topmost', 'true')
progress_window.configure(bg = 'lightgrey')
progress_window.wm_title("Progress")
progress_window_label  =  Label(root, text = "")
progress_window.geometry('600x300')
progress_window_label.pack()

M = 4 # outer loop
N = 5 # inner loop

progress1_var = DoubleVar()
progress1bar = Progressbar(master = progress_window, variable = progress1_var, length = M)    
progress1bar.pack(side = TOP, ipady = 5, fill = BOTH, expand = True)
progress1_var.set(0)
progress1bar.update()
progress1bar_label = Label(master = progress_window, text = 'Bar1', bg = 'lightgray')
progress1bar_label.pack(side = TOP, pady = 5, fill = BOTH, expand = True)

progress2_var  =  DoubleVar()
progress2bar = Progressbar(master = progress_window, variable = progress2_var, length = N)
progress2bar.pack(side = TOP, ipady = 5, fill = BOTH, expand = True)

progress2_var.set(0)
progress2bar.update()

progress2bar_label = Label(master = progress_window, text = 'Bar2', bg = 'lightgray')
progress2bar_label.pack(side = TOP, pady = 5, fill = BOTH, expand = True)

def process():
    for t in range(M):
        if killed:
            break
        progress1_var.set(t/M)
        progress1bar_label.config(text = "Bar 1:    " + str( round( (t+1)/M*100, 3)) + "%")
        progress1bar.update()
        progress2_var.set(0)
        progress2bar.update()
        for i in range(N):
            progress2_var.set(i/N)
            time.sleep(1.0)
            if killed:
                break
            progress2bar_label.config(text = "Bar 2:    " + str( round( (i+1)/N*100, 3)) + "%")
            progress2bar.update()

stop_button = Button(master = progress_window, text = "Cancel", command = stop)
stop_button.pack(side = TOP, pady = 5, fill = BOTH, expand = True)

root.after( 1000, process )
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Very nice! Just a couple questions. For my actual, more involved script, the progressbars are created within a lengthy function taking six arguments. When progress_window is closed, I want root to remain open since it will contain a figure canvas. I assume then that root.destroy() would be removed from the above. Also, the root.after(1000,process) combined with root.update() are really just taking the place of the timer?

Comment: I suggest moving away from `sleep` and using `after`, although this would require a fairly radical change to your core program. I also noticed your main `root` window wasn't doing much, i assumed you would be able to continue developing your code. If you don't want to close all windows then create another function specifically for the `root` but identical to `stop` (you may need to make another `killed` flag and link it to `protocol'.